# Linear Transition for Padding .3s

Tags: css, transition, padding

I'm trying to make a nice transition effect for my `navbar` items where on hovering they will smoothly change position with padding using the `linear` `transition-timing-function` over `.3` seconds.

Here is what I've tried:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    transition: .3 linear; /* I need to figure out what to do in this line */
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Would the items themselves change positions?

Comment: No, just the padding of the `<a>` tag would change. Now that I think of this? Would I need to use jQuery to set this change? If there's no solution using pure CSS, let me know so I can edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anchor `a` will need `display: inline-block;` and move the `transition` to the anchor rule

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgray;
  padding-top: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  transition: padding-top .3s linear, padding-bottom .3s linear;
}
a:hover {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a>This is a link</a>
```

Comment: @frederick99 `ease` or `linear` is cosmetics, naming transition properties is a good habit, especially in a case like this, when one don't know if all properties was provided

Comment: I cannot understand and have been looking for references online but couldn't find. Will you please provide few links or references to _naming transition properties_?

Comment: @frederick99 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions .... check section "Multiple animated properties example" .... and here is another: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property